# Uniqueness of Brownian Motion from properties

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, wiener-measure

I am trying to understand how the following properties for a stochastic process

1. $B_t$ is a Gaussian process
2. $B_t$ has independent increments
3. $t\to B_t(\omega)$ is continuous for almost all $\omega$

Uniquely determine that a process is a Brownian process centered at some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This post talks about knowing all the finite distributions will tell us that the measure for the stochastic process is uniquely generated by the set of all finite distributions: [Uniqueness of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492994/uniqueness-of-brownian-motion). My guess is that I will need to show that these three properties uniquely determine the finite distributions, but I have no idea how to generate finite the finite distributions with these properties.

Edit: Does Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem imply that the measure generated is unique?

Comment: Isn't stationary increments also required?

Comment: It may, these were just the only properties that we proved so I was wondering if they uniquely determine brownian motion

Comment: I think uniqueness requires stationary increments. If the increments are allowed to be merely of Gaussian nature but not the same, I think uniqueness is violated. However, you say "we proved" these properties : so what was your definition of the Brownian motion, with which you were able to prove these?

Comment: We used Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem on the collection of all finite distributions to give the existence of a process.

Comment: That is ok, but you must have a (mathematical) description of the finite dimensional distributions, right? Otherwise, if you don't know the f.d.distributions, how would you get the above properties? Besides, the continuity criterion comes afterwards : there is a unique (up to modification) process which is Gaussian with stationary independent increments. It exists by specifying its f.d.ds and using Kolmogorov extension. The existence of a continuous modification is shown by the Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem, et voila the Brownian motion.

Comment: Finally, according to the Kolmogorov extension theorem, the measure generated is unique, because the proof proceeds via extending the f.d.ds to so called cylindrical sets, which happen to generate the sigma-algebra for the space on which the bigger measure is sitting. So, every set in that sigma-algebra is approximated by the f.d.ds, ergo two processes having the same fdds will have the same extension.

Comment: Yes we do have the finite dimensional distributions when we construct a process that becomes Brownian motion. But I am wondering if there are properties that only Brownian motion can in the way that these characteristics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process imply a Wiener process.

Comment: Yes, and those properties are the ones you've listed as 1,2,3 above, along with stationary increments. (In textbooks, stationary and independent increments are combined and written as one point)